# Referencing yaml variables in AzurePowerShellV5 inline script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have a Azure DevOps yaml pipeline, that looks (a bit like) like this:

```yaml
variables:
  MyVar: Test

Steps:
  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    displayName: 'Test variables from yml file'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: MyServiceConnection
      ScriptType: InLineScript
      InLine: |
        Write-Host "I really want to see the values from the variables in the yml file here"
        Write-Host "parameters from the yml file would be great too"
        Write-Host "But what would I write to do that?"
        Write-Host "$(MyVar) <- Nothing here"
        Write-Host "$(variables.MyVar) <- Nothing here"
        Write-Host "$DoesThisWork <- Nothing here"
        Write-Host "$OrThis <- Nothing here"
      env:
        DoesThisWork: $(MyVar)
        OrThis: $(variables.MyVar)
```

How do I use MyVar in the InLine script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stripped it down to the simplest possible and it works just fine:

```yaml
pool: 
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables: 
  myVar: test value

steps:
  - powershell: Write-Host "$(myVar)"
```

generates:

[image: Run result]

I modified your example to remove the `env` block which did not compile, and remove the incorrect variable references:

```yaml
pool: 
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables: 
  myVar: test value

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'My Service Connection Name'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      Write-Host "I really want to see the values from the variables in the yml file here"
            Write-Host "parameters from the yml file would be great too"
            Write-Host "But what would I write to do that?"
            Write-Host "$(MyVar) <- Nothing here"
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

and got:

[image: Corrected result]

It didn't get past the first one because the syntax `$(variables.MyVar)` is invalid. The syntax works as follows:

- Compile time (usable only in the file in which the variable is declared and not to nested files like templates): `${{ variables.MyVar }}`
- Runtime (before task execution): `$(MyVar)` - expands to "$(MyVar)" if empty
- Runtime (designed for conditions, or where the default value causes problems): `$[variables.MyVar]` - expands to empty string if empty

I'm wondering if the lack of an Azure Powershell version was part of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you specify an `env` block, it creates the variables as environment variables.

In PowerShell, you reference environment variables with `$env:VariableName`. So in your case, `$env:DoesThisWork`.